# How can I render/respond_with a record that's is from an unrelated model/controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm using ActiveModelSerializers for much of my JSON API.

I have a User model, users_controller, and user_serializer for example. In my users_controller, I render my json via the following...

```
user = User.find_by_id(param[:id])
respond_with user, serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer
```

Now, I also have a Comment model, comments_controller and comment_serializer. I do the same thing from comments_controller to render it's json.

```
comment = Comment.find_by_id(param[:id])
respond_with comment, serializer: Api::V1::CommentSerializer
```

Both work great.

However, let's say I want to also render my User alongside my Comment in the comments controller. I can't even get the user to display out. If I temporarily get rid of the comment code and do something like this just for testing purposes...

```
#comment = Comment.find_by_id(param[:id])
#respond_with comment, serializer: Api::V1::CommentSerializer
user = User.find(1)
respond_with user, serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer //error on this line
```

I will get the following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_url' for #<Api::V1::CommentsController:0x007b828f407218>):
```

Why is this. How can I use AMS and respond_with another item? Preferably both at the same time, using their respective serializers?

Answer (score 0):

Try making user an instance variable by calling it:

```
@user = User.find(1)
comment = Comment.find_by_id(param[:id])
respond_with comment, serializer: Api::V1::CommentSerializer
```

Because it is an instance variable, you can now call it in your view without passing it.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

You can make as many instance variables in your controller as you want.

You could also try:

```
  respond_with(@user, @comment) serializer: Api::V1::CommentSerializer
```